# For two non-negative functions f and g, prove or disprove if f = O(g) and g = O(f) and ∀n,f(n) > g(n) then f − g = O(1)

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I am a bit confused about how to utilize the asymptotic analysis to prove this statement. I've tried to use the definition of `f = O(g)` and `g = O(f)`, namely `0<f<=c*g(n)` and `0<g <= c2*f(n)`,however I can deduce what will happen for `f(n)-g(n)`. Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not (yet) a computer programming question. Right now, it's a mathematics question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/ is probably better place for this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a lot of counterexamples. A simple one is: `f(n) = 2n` and `g(n) = n`. You can see `2n \in O(n)` and `n \in O(2n)` by definition. But, `f(n) - g(n) = n` that is obviously not in `O(1)`.